# Folder's context menu item "paste" and "paste shortcut" disabled

Tags: c++, shell, winapi, mfc, contextmenu

I am fetching folder's context menu using **IShellView::GetItemObject** (using flag: SVGIO_BACKGROUND).

Context menu is populating fine (same as window explorer populates for folder when we make a right click in an free/empty space).

Problem is in my context menu's menu-item **paste** and **paste shortcut** are disabled while there is an entry in clipboard. (Also windows context menu for folder showing them as enable).

```
GetObjectContextMenu(const LPSHELLFOLDER lpParentFolder,
                     const LPITEMIDLIST lpRelativeIDL, DWORD dwFlags, bool fIsEmptySpace) const {
    LPCONTEXTMENU lpcm;
    LPSHELLVIEW lpsv;

    HRESULT hResult= S_FALSE;
    LPSHELLFOLDER lpFolder = NULL;

    hResult = lpParentFolder->
                CreateViewObject(m_pOwnerWnd!=NULL ? m_pOwnerWnd->GetSafeHwnd() : NULL, IID_IShellView,
                (void**)&lpsv);

    lpParentFolder->AddRef();

    if(FAILED(hResult))
         return NULL;

    hResult = lpsv->GetItemObject(SVGIO_BACKGROUND, IID_IContextMenu, (LPVOID*)&g_pcm);

    if(FAILED(hResult))
        return NULL;

    if(SUCCEEDED(g_pcm->QueryInterface(IID_IContextMenu2, (void**)&g_pcm2)))
    {
        if(!SUCCEEDED(g_pcm->QueryInterface(IID_IContextMenu3, (void**)&g_pcm3)))
        {
            //&g_pcm3 = NULL;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //&g_pcm2 = NULL;
    }

    HMENU hMenu=::CreatePopupMenu();
    if(hMenu==NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    hResult=g_pcm->QueryContextMenu(hMenu,0,1,0x7fff, dwFlags );
    if(FAILED(hResult))
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    char _name[100] = {0};

    if(fIsEmptySpace)
        lpsv->Release();

    g_pcm->Release();

    if( lpFolder != NULL)
    {
        lpFolder->Release();
    }
    return hMenu;
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `AddRef()` and `Release()` on the parent `IShellFolder`? You don't need to do that, especially since you don't call `Release()` if any errors occur. In fact, all of your error checks are failing to call `Release()` before calling `return NULL` on any interfaces you successfully obtained beforehand. You are also not calling `Release()` on the `IShellView` when fIsEmptySpace is false, which is wrong. And you are never calling `Release()` on the `IContextMenu2/3` interfaces at all. You have a lot of memory mismanagement in this code.

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau, I am accessing IContextMenu2/3 in OnInitMenuPopup(..) and I am releasing them after handling sub-menus. Regarding IShellView, fIsEmptySpace is always true, actually I have cut down some code in question to summarize the procedure I am following. Same question is mentioned in following two links [link-1](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/windows-programming/100798-simulating-explorer-cut-copy-paste-files.html) [link-2](http://microsoft.public.platformsdk.shell.narkive.com/q1VFMetv/q-for-background-context-menu)

Comment: But does the clipboard actually contain data items that are pastable within the normal context that you are simulating? What exactly do you have on the clipboard when the menu items are disabled?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, using file's context menu I am copying the file infact folder's context menu is showing **paste** menu-item and allowing paste operation, but when I click in an empty space in a folder the context menu which I am retrieving using  **IShellView::GetItemObject** is not enabling paste menu item. :( 
Do I need to initialize something before calling **GetItemObjefct**. (as we call CoInitialize when require to call COM on a thread) ?